# Outlook rule for decline message with proposed new date

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I created a rule to send all invitation answers (accept, decline, tentative) to a selected folder. I would like to introduce exception when a new date/time is proposed. I cannot use the subject text becuase is language dependant. There is a field (in the form) named "proposed" which is not language sensitive. I cannot find the way to get it in the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the condition below to skip mail whose subject contains "New Time Proposed":

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I did but this subject is language dependent and if it depends on the sender's settings...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I missed the "language dependent" condition in my previous reply. In this situation, I have no idea how this can be accomplished. But if your purpose is to have a more intuitive view of the meeting responses, you may check the tracking status using Scheduling Assistant:
[image]